# Curl e Laravel, redireciona sempre

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, libcurl

Eu estou a tentar fazer um curl simples a uma app Laravel (5.2) a correr na minha máquina:

```
curl -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:7.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/7.0.1" http://192.168.1.65:8000/pt
```

Com este resultado:

**request header (header da requisição)**:

```
*   Trying 192.168.1.65...
* Connected to 192.168.1.65 (192.168.1.65) port 8000 (#0)
> GET /pt/ HTTP/1.1
> Host: 192.168.1.65:8000
> Accept: */*
> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:7.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/7.0.1
```

**response header/body (header e corpo da resposta)**:

```
< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
< Host: 192.168.1.65:8000
< Connection: close
< X-Powered-By: PHP/7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.2
< Set-Cookie: lang=pt; expires=Fri, 04-Nov-2016 08:53:50 GMT; Max-Age=2592000; path=/
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< Location: http://192.168.1.65:8000/pt
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< Date: Wed, 05 Oct 2016 08:53:50 GMT
< Set-Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6IjNReFJiRFpYOG5USEgzaVZ4YWQ5OXc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiblBFU0FqRjJ3WFMyajJHZnBlUEMzT2lXK2ZDaGpTVDJnQnZZSXdSNUhTUHQ2QmxjcUZGUDFOUit0NzFKeUxMY28zaUl0VlVBNGtUMUJmYnlxWisrT3c9PSIsIm1hYyI6IjZjZmFlZTcwNGMxOTE1OGM2NjE1ZWM5OWViZjEzMjZmYzIwZTljNWMwYWY1ZmQzZGI3Y2FjZDdiM2Q4Y2IxMmQifQ%3D%3D; expires=Wed, 05-Oct-2016 10:53:50 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/
< Set-Cookie: laravel_session=eyJpdiI6IjJ5MTMwYXBpVDlqRTZ6U2NmNjBWb3c9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiTm10QklTZTAydURkeU1kSm9Eam1UaGg1RlpvQWpncTBJTmRSd2poT01ORVRUa2l3MzNSSjJZTStPMWpGTVdYQ0JFRkt3M2ZUd3NRYVNTS3JLQkpLckE9PSIsIm1hYyI6IjM5MmQ2YzEzNDYwM2M5YTc1MzI0ODZmMjBiYWZiNmYyM2Q4NzE0ZTEyOWE3NWUzZjRjMGIxMGFjMGVjZDgzNGIifQ%3D%3D; expires=Wed, 05-Oct-2016 10:53:50 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; HttpOnly
< 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;url=http://192.168.1.65:8000/pt" />

        <title>Redirecting to http://192.168.1.65:8000/pt</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        Redirecting to <a href="http://192.168.1.65:8000/pt">http://192.168.1.65:8000/pt</a>.
    </body>
* Closing connection 0
```

Acho muito estranho, pois se usar a biblioteca requests de python 3.x:

```
import requests

headers = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:7.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/7.0.1'}
req = requests.get('http://192.168.1.65:8000/pt/', headers=headers)
print(req.text)
```

Já me é devolvido como resposta todo o html da página (isto é o que é suposto acontecer)

PS: Também já usei a *flag* `-L` com o meu `curl` para seguir os redirecionamentos e fica em loop infinito (`curl: (47) Maximum (50) redirects followed`)

Porque isto acontece? Como resolver, e conseguir fazer o *request* com curl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvido, ao que parece a biblioteca requests (mesmo sem usar `Session()`) retem os cookies e coloca-os no header de requisição do redirecionamento, neste caso é o cookie da linguagem `..../pt` que, pelo design da app, é sempre obrigatório existir e sendo por default o PT. O problema é que o curl ao seguir o redirecionamento não colocava no header da requisição este cookie, resultando então num loop infinito de redirecionamentos, ou seja, o comando correto para que com `curl` dê certo é:

```
curl -c cookies.txt -A 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:49.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/49.0' -Lv http://192.168.1.65:8000/pt
```

Em que estou a gravar os cookies definidos nos headers de resposta num ficheiro para os usar também no proximo redirecionamento

Ou, também posso definir o cookie manualmente, sem precisar de ficheiro:

```
curl -A 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:49.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/49.0' -b lang=pt http://192.168.1.65:8000/pt
```